# XSLT Adding parameters in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

This is code from the W3 website with a small modification to be able to set parameters, but it currently only works for FF, Opera, etc. I need to call the Transform function whenever someone picks something from a dropdown, to send a parameter and display different things. How can I modify the code to set parameters in IE?

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
 xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function Transform()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "derp", derp);
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762312(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)